# Pipe stdout to with multiple lines to individual files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a kafka consumer that deserializes avro messages and prints to stdout. I want to pipe the output into files, but want a separate file for each message - not all of the messages in a single file.

I have searched google and most people want the output to multiple files or piped into another program, this is not what I am trying to do. I need each message/line into a unique files name, either with a counter, the message number from the output, or date to the millisecond.

The output is in this format:

```
AVRO MESSAGE (1): {Data in JSON format}
AVRO MESSAGE (2): {Data in JSON format}
AVRO MESSAGE (3): {Data in JSON format}
AVRO MESSAGE (4): {Data in JSON format}
```

I wish line 1 to go into a file named output1.txt or output20190518113126104, line 2 to go into a file named output2.txt or output20190518113126351
where the timestamped name is YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSS or something similar to insure it is unique.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `split` with option `l` (lines) and count 1

```
cmd | split -l1
```

When you want a prefix for your outputfiles, you can use

```
 split -l1 <(cmd) output
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comment, you can forse numeric output with `-d` and let `split` read from stdin with `-`. This makes:

```
cmd | split -l1 -d - output
```

Comment: Probably want `split -l1 -d - output.` to get numeric suffixes (zero based)

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought of `split`.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo | awk '{out="output" NR ".txt"; print > out; close(out)}'
```

replace `foo` with whatever command is currently generating your output.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the awk solution presented by Ed Morton.  The canonical method (IMO) in a shell would be:

```
cmd | { i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line" > output.$((i++)); done; }
```

You might prefer a for-loop, but IMO it's not as clean since you cannot write `for((i=1; read line; i++))` as you would like.  (The second expression cannot be a command).  eg:

```
cmd | for ((i=1;; i++)); do IFS= read -r line || break; printf '%s\n' "$line" > output.$i; done;
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of `-r`, as I usually prefer escape characters to be honored.  But in this case it is probably correct behavior to use it.

Comment: `printf '%s' "$line"` would be better, as POSIX `echo` would expand the escape sequence you just tried to preserve with `-r`.

Comment: Well, that's news to me!  Stick with `awk`.  But `printf '%s'` loses the newline.